# Apply colored marker over an image

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am doing line detection using a Hessian matrix over an image. The main objective is to detect points on the image and mark it with color. I've got the matrix and looping over it and checking over a condition and if the condition is true, I want to put a red marker over the image.

The code is as follows:

```
for_corners = np.copy(img)
for_edges = np.copy(img)

for row, response in enumerate(detA):
    for col, r in enumerate(response):
        if r > 0:
            # corner detected
            for_corners[row, col] = [255,0,0]
        elif r < 0:
            # edge detected
            for_edges[row, col] = [0,255,0]
```

img: input image
detA: output for the hessian detector

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

on this line,

```
for_corners[row, col] = [255,0,0]
```

Comment: [255,0,0] is for red
[0,255,0] is for green

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I understood where I went wrong @furas I searched for a fix and saw that I can add points by assigning the image in a numpy.dstack and assigning the color that way.

Comment: Post an answer, instead of editing the question to contain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.dstack to assign the colors

```
for_corners = np.dstack([img, img, img])
for_edges = np.dstack([img, img, img])

for row, response in enumerate(detA):
    for col, r in enumerate(response):
        if r > 0:
            # corner detected
            for_corners[row, col, :] = [1,0,0]
        elif r < 0:
            # edge detected
            for_edges[row, col, :] = [0,1,0]
```

The RGB values are scaled between 0 and 1.